# There is a way to invoke a maven plugin without plugging it in every pom.xml

Tags: maven, plugins

I just started using maven.
I need to automate the build of several projects developed by different programmers. I would like to know if there is a way to invoke a custom plugin without plugging in any pom.xml (several hundred).
For example, I could enter the use of the plugin in the settings.xml file?

Comment: What kind of custom plugin do you use for what purpose? Bound it to the life-cycle ?

Comment: Using a plugin created to analyze the pom.xml for example if you use a specific parent pom.
this plugin is launched to install or deploy

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parent POM and add your definition there. If you don't use one already the first time around you'll have to modify all your POM's. On the other hand, you'll then be able to add new definitions to the parent POM and they will be seen by all your POM's.

This [blog post](http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.it/2011/12/maven-aggregator-vs-parent.html) is worth reading.

Comment: The problem is that if the developer do not include the parent pom, the plugin is not executed.